# parse server masterkey error

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

i m trying job for the first time and stucked up in the unauthorized master key  error....can some body guide me

```
Parse.Cloud.job( 'testjob', function ( request, status ){

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({

        url: 'http://localhost:1337/parse/functions/hello'
    },{useMasterKey:true}).then(function(httpResponse) {
        // success
        console.log(httpResponse.text);
        status.success('OK');
    },function(httpResponse) {
        // error
        status.error('ERROR: ' + httpResponse.status);
        console.error('ERROR: ' + httpResponse.status);
    });

});
```

//my index cofig file

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/pingin',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN ||'./cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'my app id',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'my key', 
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is your master key, and how did you configure or acquire it?

Comment: @cricket_007 my master key is in node js server config file called as "server.js"   following is my config file

Comment: Please [edit] the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting unauthorised because your http request doesn't contain application ID and user credentials (if required)... I suppose this job is defined in your main.js so you can just call hello function just as any javascript function

Comment: ....As you said i can achieve using javascript function but my intention is to try out  job using parse server

Comment: as I said, you need to include app ID of the parse app to communicate with it, try using curl command to run your url request without and with the app ID included and you will see

Answer (score 0):

`useMasterKey:true` can be used in Cloud Code along with Queries only. Cloud HTTP Request is just like node.js request module, it just sends the request after setting the header and body parameter. If you want to pass the masterkey in an HTTP request, pass it as `X-Parse-Master-Key` header in the request headers.

Please see here for details regarding REST API guides. The request that you are making is a REST API call, though its to the same server.